# What backups are on my mac?

Tags: macos, backup

According to System Information, I have about 57 GB of "Backups". What exactly is meant by "backups"? I'm guessing iPad and iPhone backups count, but that only accounts for ~25 GB.

Where is the rest?

Comment: I have several macs with more than 3 GB of iOS device backups in ~/Library and they all report "Zero KB" of backup space. If `tmutil snapshot` reports an error, then it's not local storage (or it needs cleaning up). Is your time machine control panel showing local backups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These files are stored in /.MobileBackups/ and /.DocumentRevisions-V100/.

I am very surprised that your backup is so large - my Backups are only 300MB!

According to the Time Machine preference pane, TM will "keep local snapshots as space permits". Do you have a lot of spare disk space?

Since these folders are owned by root, to check the size of these folders you'll need to use sudo, or log in as root user. E.g. the command line commands:

```
sudo du -hs .DocumentRevisions-V100/
sudo du -hs .MobileBackups/
```